# For some reason I can't seem to access my shared folder created on ubuntu virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, samba, automount, shared-folders

I've created a shared folder on my ubuntu virtualbox to share files with my windows 10 host system. But I when I click the shared folder, it says the locations could not be displayed? I don't have the permission.

how do I fix this?

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf shared ~/guest_shared
```

This is my command above, a shared folder was created but I can't access it

Comment: From your question it is not clear which of the two operation systems is the guest and which one is the host. Can you clarify please?

Comment: Sir I was able to create a shared folder on my ubuntu, but when I click it, it says the location cannot be displayed and I don't have the permisson.

Comment: sudo mount -t vboxsf shared ~/guest_shared

Comment: hey sir it's so weird now I can't type too long, can you email me? gethbonow on gmail

Answer (score 0):

Add user to vboxsf group.

`sudo usermod -G vboxsf -a <username>`

Make sure to log out. When you log back in

```
~$ id
... 999(vboxsf)
```

if you see this, you should have access to your shared folder.

Comment: sir I redited my question, I posted the command I used.

Comment: sir it's 16. It's really weird now after that command I used, two shared folder was created. the sharedwindows10 works perfect, but another shared folder was created and I can't access it. So I'm deleting both folder and creating folder again using that command.

Comment: sir can you email me gethbonow@gmail.com better to share screenshots on there.

Comment: Instead of `cat /etc/group` you should use the command `id` to check what groups you are in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command first

```
sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-utils
```

and then

```
sudo usermod -aG vboxsf $(whoami)
```

after that you can reboot the OS.